# Frame.Navigate not working

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I recently added a new page in the project and am trying to Navigate to it through a button click event using Frame.Navigate(typeof()). It isn't working. The code runs and compiles with no errors and I've even added breakpoints to see whether it's executing the Navigate statement. It does but  it's returning false. The page stays as is. I then tried replacing it to another page which was originally there in my project and the statement ran just fine for that. Please Help!

Comment: Make sure the page you're trying to navigate to inherits from Page. I already got bitten once trying to navigate (involuntarily) to a usercontrol

Comment: Yes it does inherits.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out the problem with given description. But, you can handle the [NavigationFailed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigationfailed.aspx) event to respond to navigation failure or You can handle the failure directly in the event handler, or you can set the [NavigationFailedEventArgs.Handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationfailedeventargs.handled.aspx) property to **true** and use the **Navigate** method return value to respond to the failure.

Comment: I got it to work.I had multiple textblocks in a stackpanel which was in turn inside a row of a grid. Instead of using multiple textblocks, I used a single textbox with linebreaks. That made the navigation successful. I still don't know why it wasn't working previously.